# Haskell: Why can't i use last instead of tail in this small function?

Tags: haskell

If i use tail in the following function (which is meant to exchange the numbers in a list 2 by 2) it compiles and works fine:

```
    pairExchange :: [a] -> [a]

    pairExchange [] = []
    pairExchange [a] = [a]
    pairExchange (x:xs) | length xs > 2  =  head xs : x : pairExchange (tail xs)
                        | otherwise  =  head xs : x : tail xs
```

but if i use "last xs" in the last line instead of "tail xs" (which would be the same since the list would only contain 2 elements) i get the following error:
"Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]"

I would like to know why that is, thank you in advance.

Comment: `tail :: [a] -> [a]; last :: [a] -> a`. That is, `last` returns an element, not a list. But you've made it the right argument to `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. Then type inference tries to treat the list as a list-of-lists and gets itself tied in knots.

Comment: Something you might enjoy puzzling over: what do you think goes wrong if you leave off the length check (and `otherwise` clause) entirely? Does GHC agree with you? (This puzzle is unrelated to your problem.)

Answer (score 4):

They have different types:

```
λ> :t last
last :: [a] -> a
λ> :t tail
tail :: [a] -> [a]
```

Therefore `last xs` has type *a* and `tail xs` has type *[a]*.

In this case `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]` means it found *a* when it was expecting *[a]*.

A demonstration:

```
λ> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
λ> :{ 
     f :: [a] -> [a] 
     f xs = head xs : last xs -- (1)
   :}
   <interactive>:102:35: error:
     • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
   
λ> :{ 
     f :: [a] -> [a] 
     f xs = head xs : [last xs] -- (2)
   :}
λ> f [1,2,3]
[1,3]
```

In (1) `last xs` has type *a*. In (2) `[last xs]` has type *[a]*.